# one to many- Showing list of children related to parent id

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

I have two domain class

1)

```
package opfwflowmonitor
import java.io.Serializable;
class OpfWF_Entry implements Serializable{

String name
Date create_date
static hasOne=[siteName:OpfWF_SiteName, currentStepStatus:OpfWF_CurrentStepStatus,currentStepName:OpfWF_CurrentStepName]
static hasMany = [historySteps:OpfWF_HistoryStepsInfo]

static mapping = {

            table name: "OS_WFENTRY", schema: "GSI"
            version false
            cache true
            historySteps cache:true 
            sort id:"desc"
            columns{
                    name column:'NAME'
                    create_date column:'CREATE_DATE'

    }


}
}
```

And

```
package opfwflowmonitor
import java.util.Date;
class OpfWF_HistoryStepsInfo {

Long entry_id
Long action_id
Long step_id
Date start_date
Date finish_date
String status

static belongsTo = [historyEntry: OpfWF_Entry]

static mapping = {
    table name: "OS_HISTORYSTEP", schema: "GSI"
    version false
    cache true
    historyEntry cache: true
    sort id:"desc"
    id generators: 'assigned'
    columns{
        id column:'ID'
        action_id column:'ACTION_ID'
        step_id column:'STEP_ID'
        start_date column:'START_DATE'
        finish_date column:'FINISH_DATE'
        status column:'STATUS'
    //  ENTRY_ID column:'ENTRY_ID'

        }
    historyEntry column:'entry_id'
    historyEntry insertable:false
    historyEntry updateable:false
}

String toString() { "$id" }
}
```

How i can show list of all historystep with all properties when i select OpfWF_Entry ?

How to get a list table of childs(with all properties of history table) when user click on list of OpfWF_Entry table's record.

Comment: Are you using the default scaffolding or are you writing your own views?

Comment: default scaffolding automatically generated by grails with controller.

Comment: You really should follow general java coding standards. Underscores are legacy conventions from case insensitive databases like Oracle. You should really not use them in Java/Groovy ...ever. Well OK constants can have underscores but whatever. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: DmitryB- No Grails can easy solve on own hand. I have posted answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Right- Answering my question. Here how i solved it.

1)
        From list view  of OpfWF_Entry, I have called historyStepInfo-Controller's searchme action(search me action added by myself).

2)
         In historyStepInfoController- I have added searchme action- that finds inside hisotryStepInfo domain for all matching rows using params.id(passed from list view of opfEntry)

def opfWF_HistoryStepsInfoInstanceList =OpfWF_HistoryStepsInfo.findAllByEntry_id(params.id)

render (view:'list',model:[opfWF_HistoryStepsInfoInstanceList:opfWF_HistoryStepsInfoInstanceList,opfWF_HistoryStepsInfoInstanceTotal: opfWF_HistoryStepsInfoInstanceList.count()])

3)
         Added HistoryStepsInfoInstanceList to list view of historyStepInfo "in"-varibale

And there i got all children related to a parent select.

This work for everything. Search,Children List and whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood you question correctly. The properties should be visible when you have the OpfWF_Entry object, but if in your case you can't access it, you can create a method to expose any properties you want.

Controller:

```
def showAllHistorySteps = {
   def opfwfEntry = OpfWF_Entry.findById(params.id)
   def historySteps = opfwfEntry.historySteps
   historySteps.each {
      println "Step: ${it.toString()}"
   }
   return [historySteps:historySteps]
}
```

Domain:

```
class OpfWF_HistoryStepsInfo {
   def getAllProperties() {
      // code to return a list of properties you want
   }
}
```

View:

```
 < g:each in="historySteps" > <br/>
   < g:set var="listOfProps" value="${it.getAllProperties()"/>  <br/>
   // do what you want with listOfProps  <br/>
< /g:each> <br/>
```

Comment: i want a list view from history step which show all historystep(with all properties from historystepinfo domain ) related to selected wf_entry table record.

Comment: What you basically have is a simple one-to-many relationship. If I understand you correctly you want a view with a table showing all the historySteps associated with OpfWF_Entry. You really have to add this to the view, there is no easy "scaffolding" way to do this.

Comment: Thank you ibaralf. Your answers are giving me direction.